# Extracting text from html in emacs?

Tags: html, web-browser

Are there any packages to extract text from html in emacs?

What I would like to try is to extract relevant text from `browse web` so that I can read papers and articles without the visual clutter of links and similar.

Command line scripts I can use through emacs would also be accepted even though I would prefer an emacs package.

Comment: Emacs 25.1 (as built from HEAD) has support for a "readability" feature in eww, the Emacs browser. Perhaps this can be used.

Comment: Need to upgrade then, thanks. Can't try this until the weekend most likely, but will look into it eventually.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat You can call the plain old `lynx` from `shell-command` to convert html to txt. But yes, the emacs 25.0 Readability mode is nice, it removes a lot of cluttery frames.

Comment: @kaushalmodi Lynx worked great, w3m even better! They do so much of the grunt work I was thinking of implementing that I imagine I'll require one of them for the emacs package I'm dreaming of building.

Comment: @wasamasa Sorry for the dumb question, but I can't find emacs 25 anywhere. Is it available, even if just the source? (Preferably an OS X version, but I'm pretty sure no Mac installers exist/package managers have it yet.)

Comment: You obtain it by building the development release of Emacs.